# Angular UI Router - functions inside template not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am learning to use Angular UI Router to control the different parts of the application.

Take a look at this plunkr (http://plnkr.co/edit/KH7lgNOG7iCAEDS2D3C1?p=preview)

Things not working:

- When the view is loaded the {{ logger }} value in not being updated though I have initialized it in the Homecontroller.
- Login and logout buttons dont work as expected.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be quite a complicated problem.  To apply a controller to multiple views, you'll need to apply the controller directly to the html using `ng-controller` (e.g. `ng-controller="HomeController"`.  From there, you apply individual controllers to each view.

So, to fix things up, add `controller: 'LoginController'` to the `views.navbar` object, then you'll need the following two controllers instead.

```
.controller('LoginController',
  ['$scope','userInfo',function($scope,userInfo){
    $scope.login = function(){
      $scope.model.logger += "Logged in \n";
      $scope.model.user = userInfo;
    }

    $scope.logout = function(){
      $scope.logger += "logged out \n";
      $scope.user = false ;
    }
  }])
.controller('HomeController',
  ['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.model = {
      user: null,
      logger: 'Nothin to log yet :'
    };
  }]);
```

Here's the [updated plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LSRLfbZyNiC44gsxXGnP?p=preview) which should now work as expected.

Comment: I tried to use the 'HomeController' in the routing as I want to resolve 'userInfo' over both the views. The case where you have to check the user session info on page refresh, then I want to just resolve userInfo using a sessions service and inject into 'HomeController' so that the user sees his name when page is loaded.. any solution for this ?. Also somehow ngShow and ngHide seems to be not working .. here is the updated [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/KH7lgNOG7iCAEDS2D3C1?p=preview).

Comment: your resolve function wasn't returning a valid promise, I've updated it for you [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qljJx623U0DWLGgNTpw7?p=preview).  To save userInfo, use something like $cookieStore or $window.localStorage.